# How to remove whitespace if select option checked

Tags: css, stylesheet

I have sample code:

```
<select>
<option value="1">1<option>
<option value="2"> 2<option>
<option value="3">  3<option>
<option value="4">   4<option>
<option value="5">    5<option>
</select>
```

And css:

```
select option:checked {
   padding-left: 0;
   text-align:left;
}
```

When I checked option (2 or 3 or 4 or 5), I can't remove whitespace, how to fix it ?

This is attachment:

[image: Select box dropdown]

Answer (score 2):

Actually you're adding each `<option>` twice, You could either close `<option>` elements by `</option>` or remove the extra `<option>` element from the end.

> **[Tag omission](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html#option-tags)**
>
> - An `option` element must have a start tag.
> - An `option` element’s end tag may be omitted if the `option` element is immediately followed by another `option` element.

Besides, leading or trailing white spaces in HTML are ignored by default:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/basuq/2/watch)**

```
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2"> 2</option>
  <option value="3">  3</option>
  <option value="4">   4</option>
  <option value="5">    5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Oh no, When dropdown, value will show with level + whitespace, When you selected option value is result show it will remove whitespace

Comment: @haitruonginfotech I don't see any white space there, would you mind posing a screenshot to illustrate that space?

Comment: above attachment image

Comment: @haitruonginfotech Thanks, however it seems that the drop down is styled via JavaScript probably or some CSS tricks, and it's completely different than the code you've provided. Therefore we're unable to guess what causes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that removes leading & trailing white spaces in the text of all options.

```
$('select > option').each(function(){
    var textValue = $.trim($(this).text());
    $(this).text(textValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1 2 3 4 5

---

Close option tag correctly